# Is changing the "spritePixelsToUnits" property from the meta file more efficient than using the "transform" option to resize a texture?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm playing around with the unity and I'm making a basic 2D game. I remember hearing in a tutorial that resizing textures using the "transform box" is inefficient. I have discovered that I can also change the size  by editing the "spritePixelsToUnits" property in the meta file. Which of these methods is more efficient? Is tampering with the meta files considered as bad practise?

EDIT: I want to change it's size only in the editor

Comment: Do you mean at runtime or in the editor? And only once or dynamically? In general I would rather not manipulate the meta files manually ;)

Comment: I would think meta files control the importing of assets, not their runtime properties, so there would be no effect during runtime? Are they even present in a runtime environment?

Comment: Well the question is again at which moment do you want to change the size of your sprite? You would probably rather change that property on the Texture via the Inspector in Unity .. or you change the object where you use that sprite .. e.g. if it is a `RawImage` simply change its `transform.localScale` according to your needs. The `spritePixelsToUnits` could only be changed on runtime by everytime creating a new sprite ;) (`Sprite.Create`)

Answer (score 0):

The .meta file is generated by unity to "remember" the options assigned to a particular file.
While editing it being a bad practice or not is debatable, most option are accessible through Unity's inspector and you should avoid editing the meta file unless you're absolutely sure about what you're doing.

Regarding the original question about resizing texture, if you want to change a size only in the editor you can use the transform box without efficiency problem.
Another solution if you want a bigger or smaller texture is simply to edit it using Gimp or whatever image manipulation software you're familiar with.

If you want to change a texture size at runtime, using the Transform property can be inefficient, and texture manipulation through script can get you improved performance.
However, I would avoid any early optimization that may be unnecessary and complexify your code or project.

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil